# Why is npm saying 404 when curl can 200

Tags: npm, artifactory

I added a registry like `myscope:registry=https://myprivatedomain.com/artifactory/api/npm/npm-myregistry-release/` to my `.npmrc` file.

When I do `npm install @myscope/mypackage` it says 404 Not Found. When I cat the debug log it has the error `7 http fetch GET 404 https://myprivatedomain.com/artifactory/api/npm/npm-myregistry-release/@myscope%2fmypackage 1463ms` which is odd because if I do `curl https://myprivateregistry.com/@myscope%2fmypackage` I see a response. Any idea what I may have configured wrong?

Using `-i` on curl gives me all the appropriate things you'd expect, like 200:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 20 Jul 2018 19:03:17 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Server: Artifactory/5.10.3
X-Artifactory-Id: 3cfb3447e11ab4943a37f53d7a5dcd357274261d
X-Artifactory-Node-Id: art2
ETag: c3636860e64da7eda14f65ff25c1e8ad11266adc
```

I did `npm search @myscope` and found nothing. I then updated `.npmrc` to just be `registry=https://myprivatedomain.com/artifactory/api/npm/npm-myregistry-release/` and ran the search. I saw the package come up. Despite search working now, it still says 404 when I go to install.

I had my coworker use the same npm config and it worked for him. I closed out my terminals and restarted (in case I had somehow set something poorly using npm login, as a sanity check) and still have the issue. If I do `npm logout` and try the install, I get a 401. I then did `npm login` again and got back to the `E404`

I also went into my `.gitconfig` and commented out `insteadOf` like so:

```
#[url "https://"]
#       insteadOf = git://
```

Honestly not sure why that's in there, but seemed like it was worth a shot to comment out just for this.

Comment: Are you using some kind of proxy oder vpn?

Comment: Are you using the same user with npm login as in curl? sounds like a permission thing

Comment: @KeKsBoTer I am on same network as coworker who has no issue.

Comment: @danf I was thinking something along the lines of npm login as well. I feel like I've logged into multiple locations tho. If I am using curl, wouldn't that imply I am anonymous so ANY login would work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there was some config issue on the registry's end. Writing this as a placeholder. Hoping to get registry owner to write what they did to correct this. Very bizarre since it wasn't impacting everyone.

Comment: Strange indeed. I have edited my answer with a possible explanation.

Answer (score 0):

From the [official Artifactory documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Npm+Registry), the correct URL should be:

```
npm config set registry http://<ARTIFACTORY_SERVER_DOMAIN>:8081/artifactory/api/npm/npm-repo/
```

In your case: `myprivateregistry.com/api/npm/npm-repo`: check with your colleague (who has no issue) what his/her `.npmrc` references.

From the OP, the artifact on the registry end was flawed.
One explanation for it *not* affecting the other colleague was said colleague had it in his/her local npm cache.

Comment: I was using the short domain as an example since the real domain is a private URL I'd probably get in trouble for posting, even though it is only accessible on our networks :) I'll make it more realistic above. But also AFAIK, using `.npmrc` means I don't need to do `npm config set`

Comment: @DaveStein `npm config` set configures `.npmrc`.

Comment: Ah a little confusion on my part. However I had my coworker copy paste my npmrc and it worked for him either way.

Comment: @DaveStein So I suspect an authentication issue, meaning credentials are not properly set in your case. Or your user on Artifactory side does not have the right to access that npm repo.

Comment: do you think there is an NPM bug then? In that it's saying a 404 when it's really a permissions thing? I mean like it says above, if I logout I get a 401 which is what I would expect

Comment: @DaveStein Sometimes, 404 can be sent instead of 403 or 401, in order to *not* reveal a permission issue on the application side. I would look into the permissions associated with your account on the Artifactory Admin side.

Comment: Registry allows anon reads for now (although it's changing in the future)

Comment: @DaveStein So there is no difference in .npmrc between you and your colleague? How about environment variable? Does he/she has a NO_PROXY variable? Or any other environment variable which might differ with yours?

Comment: AFAIK we have no such env variables set like that. Not like either of us would have manually done that. Unless new macs set that (his) and old ones don't (mine)

Comment: @DaveStein Still: env would print all environment variables: you can compare the list between you and your colleague's.

Comment: `env | grep NO_PROXY` comes up blank for both of us